# Javascript function is not calling on mobile

Tags: javascript, android, internet-explorer, mobile, cross-browser

I have script function and its working on laptop but it not calling on mobile (checked on Androids only). Even not displaying simple alert message.

What can be reason for this?

This is link:

```
 <a href="javascript:void(0)"
              onclick="doit(id='<?php echo $results[$i]->ID; ?>', color = '<?php echo get_post_meta($pid, 'color', true);?>',color2='<?php echo get_post_meta($pid, 'color2', true);?>',
                  unit_size='<?php echo get_post_meta($pid, 'unit_size', true);?>', unit_size2='<?php echo get_post_meta($pid, 'unit_size2', true);?>',col_unit_gst='<?php echo get_post_meta($pid, 'col_unit_gst', true);?>',
                  col_unit_Xgst='<?php echo get_post_meta($pid, 'col_unit_Xgst', true);?>',col2_unit2_Xgst='<?php echo get_post_meta($pid, 'col2_unit2_Xgst', true);?>',
                  col2_unit2_gst='<?php echo get_post_meta($pid, 'col2_unit2_gst', true);?>')" value="<?php echo $results[$i]->ID;?>" class="mycls<?php echo $pid;?>"><button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">For Price</button></a>
```

Here is function created

```
            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Price List</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <script language="JavaScript">
                        function doit (id='', color = '',color2='', unit_size='', unit_size2='',col_unit_gst='', col_unit_Xgst='',
                                       col2_unit2_Xgst='', col2_unit2_gst=''){

                            alert('Yes we are here');
                            document.getElementById('color').innerHTML = color;
                            document.getElementById('unit_size').innerHTML = unit_size;
                            document.getElementById('col_unit_gst').innerHTML = col_unit_gst;
                            document.getElementById('col_unit_Xgst').innerHTML = col_unit_Xgst;

                           /* document.getElementById('id').innerHTML = id; */
                            document.getElementById('color2').innerHTML = color2;
                            document.getElementById('unit_size2').innerHTML = unit_size2;
                            document.getElementById('col2_unit2_Xgst').innerHTML = col2_unit2_Xgst;
                            document.getElementById('col2_unit2_gst').innerHTML = col2_unit2_gst;

                        }
                    </script>


                 <div class="ratelist-heading">
                 <ul class="head">
                 <li>Colour
                 </li>
                 <li>Unit Size
                 </li>
                 <li>ex.GST
                 </li>
                 <li>Incl.GST
                 </li>
                 </ul>

                 <ul class="ratelist">
                 <li><p style="float: none;" id="color"></p> <p style="float: none;" id="color2"></p></li>
                 <li><p style="float: none;" id="unit_size"></p> <p style="float: none;" id="unit_size2"></p></li>
                 <li><p style="float: none;" id="col_unit_Xgst"></p> <p style="float: none;" id="col2_unit2_Xgst"></p></li>
                 <li><p style="float: none;" id="col_unit_gst"></p> <p style="float: none;" id="col2_unit2_gst"></p></li>
                 </ul>


                 </div>  


                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Update: This is also not working in Internet Explorer 11. Seems to be browser compatibility issue.

Comment: We cannot help you if you dont provide enough info

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: Code is added and post updated

Comment: is it working in the emulated mode in browser

Comment: Yes, its working in emulated mode of browser

Comment: Its working on firefox,chrome but not in IE 10.

Comment: wer your trying. in app

Comment: Its site not app. Can I post link of site here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out the error. Here are changing which i made:

```
                            function doit (id, color,color2, unit_size, unit_size2,col_unit_gst, col_unit_Xgst,
                                       col2_unit2_Xgst, col2_unit2_gst)
```

Previously i was passing as :

```
function doit (id='', color = '',color2='', unit_size='', unit_size2='',col_unit_gst='', col_unit_Xgst='',
                                   col2_unit2_Xgst='', col2_unit2_gst='')
```

This was not working in "Internet explorer 11" and also have same issue in mobile devices. Its fixed now.

Thanks all for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if JavaScript is allowed in your phone browser? Go to settings and check if it allows JavaScript , otherwise if it doesnt allow it wont play any code.

Comment: It should work by default because I can go to enable on every mobile.

Comment: @Jai have you tried debugging your Android phone through USB? You can follow an easy tutorial to set up USB debugging, and then use chrome dev tools on your computer to diagnose your code that is running on your phone. This way, you can check for JavaScript errors, or walk through the code line-by-line.